# Deploy Springboot Application to Render

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, dockerfile, render.com

im trying to deploy my springboot java application (jdk 17, gradle) on render. To achieve this, i created a Dockerfile, where i did the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest AS build

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk && \
    apt-get clean

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

# Make the gradlew script executable
RUN chmod +x gradlew

RUN ./gradlew bootJar --no-daemon

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/build/classes /app/classes
COPY --from=build /app/build/generated /app/generated
COPY --from=build /app/build/resources /app/resources
COPY --from=build /app/build/tmp /app/tmp

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "/app/classes:/app/generated:/app/resources:/app/tmp", "ch.mygroup.goatlistfootball.GoatListFootballApplication"]
```

My Build folder is structured the following:

build:

- classes
- generated
- resources
- tmp
- bootRunMainClassname

I am getting the following error after trying to deploy it:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ch.mygroup.goatlistfootball.GoatListFootballApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.mygroup.goatlistfootball.GoatListFootballApplication
```

I never deployed any spring boot application before, would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find the jar you compile.
And use the **java -jar JarName.jar** to start the springboot project.
The spring boot has a embeded Tomcat.
The compiled folder structure generally is
[image: The compiled folder structure]

you should extract the libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, and use the java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to run it

Comment: how can i generate this jar file? i dont have this included the libs folder

Comment: You may execute the build by gradle

Comment: What IDE you are use ,  I use the IDEA ,and can execute the command like gradle bulid to build your project